# Mental model for control plane and data plane

Tags: architecture, system-design

Question - What's the mental model people use for control plane vs data plane? How should I view control plane vs data plane for different kinds of resources?

The way I understand control vs data plane is that control plane lets you create/delete/update the resource. But once resource is created, any interaction with the resource itself or usage of it goes via data plane. For example - Every cloud has control plane that lets you create a VM or database or a keyvault etc. Afterward any interaction with DB or KV itself like creating tables, data operations etc, storing secrets etc. are all data plane operations.

The part I find confusing is "interaction with or using the resource". Now, look at a resource like Kubernetes cluster. The cluster (or resource) itself is created by a control plane. So interaction with the resource (or cluster) itself should be data plane operations. But when you read the literature, api-server etc. is considered part of control plane and interacting with api-server is control plane operations. Nodes and components on node are considered data plane components.

Another way to look at a k8s cluster could be that pod is "the resource". So any operations related to creating the pod should be control plane operation. But once pod or resource is created, then interaction with it (like network traffic etc.) is data plane. So kube-proxy would be data plane components. But even by this definition, I would think kubelet is actually control plane component as it helps in "creation" of resource.

I would really appreciate if people can share their mental model of this as I continuously getting surprised in discussions when people characterize something differently than what I had in mind.

Read about it online and on youtube, but I need a general way to look at it.

Comment: Could you please indicate that in what context are you interested about the commonalities and differences of data and control planes? The answer might be different for example in case of [Istio](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/deployment/architecture/) or [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/network-layer/what-is-the-control-plane/).

Answer (score 1):

There is no control/data plane police, so we all do have options to pick whatever definition we prefer. I like using availability SLA as one of many properties to decide if a specific functionality/service is part of a data or control plane.

For example, let's say my company operates 10 microservices to for a product (let's say video streaming). My customers may come and open accounts, control billing, view videos, etc. Some of these features are core of my customers business and some are not. I would say, streaming is a data plane here - this is the core operation for my business. Control plane features are account creation and billing - those are important, but if those are not working, the streaming is still on.

The rule of thumb for control vs data plane would be:

- data plane services do not depend on control plane ones, there is no Runtime dependency, only logical one. In other words, if my control plane services are down, my control services are still working fine (clearly new users won't be able to create new accounts, but existing users may stream as usual)
- data plane must have a better availability numbers (SLA), than control plane. This is not to say that control plane is under designed, but if I need to make a development/support trade off, I would pick data plane priorities first
- typically, we care a bit more about latency in data plane, than control plane. If I have to make a trade off on which part to optimize, I would pick data plane features as those affect my customers day to day experience